# How I can test angular directive that add @Output to element?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have directive like this, and want to test @Output value, but not understand how to do it.

Simplified directive declaration.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[valuecheck]'
})
export class ValueCheckDirective {
  @Output() myValueChanged = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
    ...
    var checkedvalue = function() {...}
    this.myValueChanged.emit(
      checkedvalue // true or false
    );
  }
}
```

And test

```
@Component({
    template: '<input type="text" valuecheck>'
})
class TestHoverFocusComponent {
}

describe('Directive: valuecheck', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestHoverFocusComponent, ValueCheckDirective]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHoverFocusComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    });

    it('testing outupt from directive', async() => {
        ...

        const directiveEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ValueCheckDirective)).nativeElement;

        // (1) `
    })
}
```

Here at (1) I want to subscribe on `myValueChanged` to test output value but directiveEl does not have property `myValueChanged`.

Comment: `<input type="text" valuecheck (myValue)="value = $event">` and then `expect(component.value).toBe(....)`

Comment: It does not work for me, maybe because ValueCheckDirective also reject values if it not a number.

Comment: Why `myValueChanged` not available at // (1)?

Comment: Could you please tell what testing framework you are using?

Comment: When you test directives in Angular you have to use a proxy component, and then test everything through that proxy. Which is what you're doing by creating a `TestHoverFocusComponent` component. So that part is correct. Your tests then interact with this component and measure the results. You don't hit anything internal on the directive directly. So you should need to query it to get an instance. Either the proxy component works as expected with the directive, or it doesn't. Does that make sense?

Comment: `So you should need to query` should have been `So you shouldn't need to query`.

Comment: @Reactgular sorry not understand you. But I figure it out how to test what I need. `const directiveInstance = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ValueCheckDirective)).injector.get(ValueCheckDirective);` and in `directiveInstance` `myValueChanged` exists.